# TYPO3 news hidePagination

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I use this [TYPO3 news extension](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/news).

I want to disable paging though typoscript. The option for it is `plugin.tx_news.settings.hidePagination` so I tried this

`plugin.tx_news {
    settings.hidePagination = 1
}`

But this doesn't work. However setting `plugin.tx_news.settings.list.paginate.itemsPerPage` to a very large value does work. But that isn't a very nice solution.

Have I missed something on how to set `hidePagination`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theres a checkbox in the tx_news plugin. 
*Additional -> Hide the pagination*
It seems to overwrite the TS (unchecked by default).

Answer (score 2):

Does

```
plugin.tx_news {
    settings.hidePagination = 1
}
```

get called in your template?

You can always check this with
`<f:debug><{settings}</f:debug>` to see what get's parsed.

Comment: it is in the template. However it always contains explicit '0'.

Answer (score 0):

The option to hide the pagination only hides the pagination in the frontend and does not show all news entries at one page. You can only set a high number to the list View to show all entries at one page. I think, there is no other solution at this time.

Answer (score 0):

To override the values set in the news plugin flexform, you have to add the field to `plugin.txnews.settings.overrideFlexformSettingsIfEmpty`.

To add the field in question to the news extension standard list add this to your TS:
`plugin.txnews.settings.overrideFlexformSettingsIfEmpty := addToList(hidePagination)`